# Can ESP8266 connect to Wi-Fi network that requires not only SSID and password but also username and password?

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Can ESP8266 connect to Wi-Fi network that requires not only SSID and password but also username and password?

It's not about web captive portal. It's about a popup that appears in Windows when you connect to the network where you have to type in username and password.

I'm using Arduino IDE.

Comment: Is the network running 802.1X NAC, or are you referring to Windows domain authentication? Note that 802.1X NAC may well use Active Directory as a credential source, but these two things are not the same.

Comment: It looks like you are talking about basic authentication, This causes the popup asking for username and password while accessing a site. If yours is basic auth, you can add the auth credentials in the header and it should work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: No, I'm not talking about basic access authentication. It's rather 802.1X NAC that I'm talking about. However, I'm not sure what is the difference between 802.1X NAC and Windows domain auth. In general, I'm designing a program for ESP8266 to use for customers and I want to support as many networks as possible.

Comment: @Defozo did you ever find out if this supported domain authentication?

Comment: No, I did not :(